# Change screen LWJGL window appers on

Tags: java, opengl, window, lwjgl, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors; when creating a LWJGL window:

```
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
Display.setFullscreen(fullScreen);
Display.setVSyncEnabled(vSync);
Display.setTitle(title);
Display.create();
```

It always appears on my left screen. Is there a parameter to set to change which screen it appears on, something like:

```
Display.setScreen(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with opengl or lwjgl. By checking the API, I'd suggest invoking the static method `Display.getAvailableDisplayModes()` and trying the modes in the array and finding an appropriate display mode you would use:

```
  DisplayMode[] displayModes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();

  Display.setDisplayMode(displayModes[0]); // try different entries here.
  Display.setFullscreen(fullScreen);
  Display.setVSyncEnabled(vSync);
  Display.setTitle(title);
  Display.create();
```

Comment: Each DisplayMode only had different sizes, they were all on the same monitor (the wrong one). I think I may have found a solution, but it's hardly neat.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Not the best solution ever, but it may work. I found a method in `Display` called `setLocation(x, y);`. This changed the position of the created display. So, after finding the screen's x and y, you should be able to use this to move the window. Thanks Juvanis, I will try to implement finding the screen's positions.